# convert String to different datetime formats

Tags: c#, datetime

My input is an annoying free text in which I need to extract the date. This date could be present in any of the formats with anomalies.

> eg. This is 9.9.12 date
>   This is 9912 date
>   This is 0992012 date 
>   Any possible format.

dMy
ddMMyy
ddMMyyyy
Mdyy etc..

I am able to validate if the text is in date format for ddMMy* but not any other. I was looking into this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1 link to see what other formats could be possible but I got no leads.

Is this correct to write like in the following method for a date format say - 9912?

```
Date.ParseExact(test.ToString,"dMy", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

If yes, the system is populating me the following err:

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Can anyone please share a reliable approach to tackle such problems?

Comment: There is no "reliable approach". `9912` is easy; what do you think `11111` is? `2011-11-1`? `2011-1-11`? This is not a programming problem, but a concept problem: you have data with information loss.

Comment: @Amadan
Yes. I do understand that. However the only condition I have to check is, if this text is in date format regardless of format. Is it possible in that scenario?

Comment: how can you tell the difference between, dMy and Mdy ?

Comment: Its not a common format for DateTime, so you need to change your input to accept only certain formats that do parse into valid format

Comment: @TheGeneral I just need to validate if there exist any date. I am thinking, if the free text can be converted into any datetime / date format, then i'll pass it as valid date otherwise not.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Could you please provide a few examples. thanks. :-)

Comment: "***dMy** ddMMyy ddMMyyyy **Mdyy** etc..*" => Unsolveable: the specifications have no pattern logic as-is. Perhaps a typographic mistake... Only solveable if the lenght of the substring match a pattern like 3 / 6 / 8: dMy ddMMyy and ddMMyyyy, hence you can detect this length and know the format.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is no single way to accomplish what you're trying to do. Specifically, because the intent is so broad, it becomes hard to infer what the user actually means (e.g. how do you differentiate month vs. day).

Depending on how you're implementing your application, you need to implement input validation.

For a console app, I can envision you using something like:

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(line, out value))
{
   // Parse-able date.
}
else
{
   // Non-parseable date.
}
```

If you're building a WPF application, you can use [binding validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation). If you're building an ASP.NET MVC application, you can also implement [model validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation). Your mileage may vary - you should definitely consider constraining what your users can feed the application.